# Insert filepath from FZF window in buffer

Tags: plugin-fzf

In the fzf plugin you can define mappings for the fzf window to open the selected file in a vertical split, etc. How can I make fzf mapping to insert the path of the selected file as a string into the current buffer? I want to use this mapping inside the fzf-window opend by `:FZF` and similar commands.

Answer (score 3):

Add FZF setup:

```
    func! s:insert_file_name(lines)
        let @@ = fnamemodify(a:lines[0], ":p")
        normal! p
    endfunc
    let g:fzf_action = { 'ctrl-r': function('s:insert_file_name')}
```

Then open `:Files` select a file and press `<c-r>`.

See `:h fzf-examples`.

Comment: If you change ":p" to ":f" it will give you the relative path

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run the underlying FZF functions to do so.

Say you intend to adapt Files to do so.

:Files probably calls fzf#run at some point. Find that call.

The sink argument of fzf#run (and grep and others) would be a function that says what to do with the selected string.

I have the following code:

```
:call fzf#run({'source': uniq(reverse(b:inserts)),'sink':function('PInsert'),'options': '-m'})
```

The source is the list of lines to select from. And PInsert would insert the selection to the buffer.

```
function! PInsert(item)
    let @z=a:item
    norm "zp
endfunction
```

So you just need to create a custom command and use PInsert as the sink argument.

Good luck.

Comment: See :h fzf ................

Comment: Instead of clobbering the z register, do `put =a:item`

Comment: It is a bit different since put works linewise.

Answer (score 0):

You could always yank it and put it. I dont know how to create fzf mappings but the right hand side would basically be something like

```
normal! yaW<C-w>pp
```

Or in “pure” Ex commands, which work linewise:

```
yank | wincmd p | put
```

Depending on how much you want to yank.

Comment: You cannot (as far as I know) use normal mode command when selecting files in the fzf promt. I have tried to clarify my question.

Comment: @Andreas see edita